# Is there any method of propagation in constraint programming- GoogleORTools like CPLEX-CP solver?

Tags: cp, constraint-programming, or-tools, propagation

I want to only propagate connection in Constraint Programming-Google OR Tools and not looking for final solution from Constraint programming  but I am unable to find such method in Google OR Tools. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: CP solver or CP-SAT ?

Answer (score 0):

Also asked and answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/BIFYQGH3XZo

> There is a somewhat weaker version.
>
> See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/858fa626959f7e386153af82756384b79f983b5a/ortools/sat/cp_model.proto#L575
>
> Set the right parameters, and collect reduced bounds from the response proto.